# What is the name of this algorithm for calculating the lowest common multiple?

Tags: algorithms

I have implemented a quite slow algorithm to calculate the **lowest common multiple** of 20 different integer values.

It is described here with an example :
http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Arithmetic/LCM.shtml

It is also described on the Least Common Multiple Wikipedia article :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple
in the section "A simple algorithm".

To make the story short, the technique is to imagine a *grid*, in which the first *row* is populated with all the different integers (one in each *column*).
Each subsequent row represents a *step* by which the lowest integer(s) will be incremented by their initial value until all integers (*columns*) are equal, the resulting value being the lowest common multiple. As you can imagne, depending of the integer values and their count, it can take a lot of *steps* to get to the answer.

Has this algorithm a name ?

Comment: Nothing in mathematics has an _official_ name, but many things have _standard_ names.

Comment: Are you interested in a faster algorithm? $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b) = ab/{\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)}$, where $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)$ can be rapidly computed with the Euclidean algorithm. Apply the above repeatedly using $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b,c)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(a,b),c)$ to get an LCM for any number of integers.

Comment: And by 'Yuck' I mean welcome to Math on Stack Exchange!